# sonicwall specific wan ip assignment

Tags: routing, sonicwall

We have a block of 6 usable IP address from our provider. I have configured the interfaces on the TZ205 router like this:

```
X0 - LAN: 192.168.1.254 Static

X1 - WAN: x.y.z.122 Static 

X2 - DMZ: in Transparent Mode for x.y.z.123 to x.y.z.125

X3 - LAN2: 192.168.3.254 Static

X4 - available
```

I need to "patch" LAN2 on X3 to go out on the 6th available public IP `x.y.z.126`. In other words, when hosts on `192.168.3.0` network check their public IP it should be reported as `x.y.z.126`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming X3 has internet connectivity, you would like for people to be able to (for example) go to whatismyip.com and see that public there? If that's the case then you need to add a route policy, but, that IP would need to have X4.

I could very well be wrong, but this is how I have seen it setup in the past.

Comment: I thought about that, but when I try to add x.y.z.126/29 to X4 it rejects it with: Error: Index of the interface.: Subnet on this interface overlaps with another interface. X1 is defined as /29, as well